# default selected radio_button in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a cleaner way of selecting a radio_button by default or if it was previously selected in one line of code?

I first tried this:

```
- if @job.new_record?
  = f.radio_button :environment_id, env.id, :checked => env.is_default
- else
  = f.radio_button :environment_id, env.id, :checked => @job.environment == env
```

I tried to refactor using this:

```
= f.radio_button :environment_id, env.id, :checked => (@job.andand.environment == env) || env.is_default
```

but the problem with that is if the default selection is AFTER the job's environment, it will select the default selection.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just set the default value for the model in the controller. That logic should not be placed in the views. I don't know exactly how that would work for you because I don't know the structure of your models or where the "default" value comes from, but if you set the default value in the controller then the radio button will be selected if it matches the env.id in your case

```
# In Controller
@job = Job.new(:environment_id => "foo")

# In the view
= f.radio_button :environment_id, "foo"
= f.radio_button :environment_id, "bar"
```

In this case, the first radio button will be selected.

Comment: default value is a field in the Environment model(job has one environment) and it can be checked using environment.is_default? also, there's a possibility there's no default environment

Comment: Okey, then set that value in the controller, should work fine

Comment: is there a solution that should not involve setting it in the controller?

Comment: Probably, but it goes against the whole MVC concept that rails has. By doing that, you lose the goodness that comes with the rails form helpers. But if you're dead set on doing it in the views, then it would be good to know a bit more about the logic you want to enforce. My guess is that IF @job has an environment_id, select that radio_button, but IF enivronment_id is nil, then use the default, is that correct?

Comment: yup that is correct(sorry it took so long to get back to this)

Answer (score 0):

use radio_button_tag

```
=radio_button_tag environment_id, env.id, (@job.andand.environment == env)
```

Comment: and what about the default? will it be checked if it's a new job?